# How to use Separate Passport api for Api and Web

Tags: laravel

There are web and api route files. Web Routes are guarded by auth and the unauthenticated users are getting redirected to login page. But my requirement is in api route file. Unauthenticated api routes should get a custom json response instead of redirection to login page.
I am new to passport feature. And I cannot change the Web routes because its made by some other developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated render method of app/Exception/Handler.php method to as follows and it worked.

```
    {

        if($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException && $request->is('api/v*'))
            {

                return Response(['success'=>-1,'statuscode'=>401,'msg'=>'Sorry, your account has been logged in from another device.'],401);
            }

                return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When a laravel request is not authorized (aka 'unauthenticated api routes') laravel throws the same exception regardless of it being a web or api route.

However, when the exception is handled/rendered by the application the response is determined by `$request->expectsJson()`, if its true it returns it as json, if not it will act as if it is a web route.

The above function checks multiple function, and returns true if any number of these is correct:

- header `X-Requested-With` === `XMLHttpRequest`
- header `Content-Type` contains `application/json`
- header `Content-Type` contains a wildcard (`*/*`)
- header `Accept` contains `application/json`

Ensure that your api request matches any of the above described headers, and in that case should return the authentication error as json.

To enforce that api routes always throw json authentication errors you could do any of these:

- override the request header in a service provider if the route is determined to be an api route. (do not try this in middleware, it might not work)
- override the exception handler in a same manner as described above
- and of course other scenarios are also possible